# Two contact forms, send to two different email addresses

Tags: email, post

I got two contact forms on my website. On in the contact section, and one in the careers section. I want to receive both forms in different email adresses.

```
<?php
include_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('adres1','test');

$mail->Subject = 'Contactverzoek via careerspagina.';

$html  = "Er is een contactverzoek gedaan via de careerspagina.<br>";
$html .= "<br>";
$html .= "<b>Naam:</b> " . $_POST['name']."<br>";
if(isset($_POST['lastname'])) {

  $html .= '<b>Achternaam: </b> ' . $_POST['lastname']."<br>";
}
$html .= "<b>E-mail:</b> " . $_POST['email']."<br>";
if(isset($_POST['telefoon'])) {

  $html .= '<b>Telefoon: </b> ' . $_POST['telefoon']."<br>";
}

if(isset($_POST['onderwerp'])) { //FIX NOG!!!
  $html .= '<b>Onderwerp: </b> ' . $_POST['onderwerp']."<br>";
}
if(isset($_POST['Werkervaring'])) {
  $html .= '<b>Werkervaring: </b> ' . $_POST['Werkervaring']."<br>";
}
if(isset($_POST['Functie'])) {
  $html .= '<b>Functie: </b> ' . $_POST['Functie']."<br>";
}
if(isset($_POST['Opleidingsniveaus'])) {
  $html .= '<b>Opleidingsniveaus: </b> ' . $_POST['Opleidingsniveaus']."<br>";
}
if(isset($_POST['comment'])) {
  $html .= '<b>Bericht: </b> ' . $_POST['comment']."<br>";
}
$html .= "<br>";

if (isset($_FILES['resume']) &&
    $_FILES['resume']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['resume']['name']);
}

if (isset($_FILES['letter']) &&
    $_FILES['letter']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['letter']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['letter']['name']);
}

$mail->msgHTML($html);
$mail->addAddress('adres1', 'Info ');
$mail->addBCC('adres1', 'Test ');

if(!$mail->send())
{
    echo "0";
}
else
{
    echo "1";
}
```

This is my code, and everything seems to work.

So once again. I want to keep sending this contact form to email A. But There needs to be made and else statement which sends the other contact form to email B.

i'm very new to PHP. Excuse me if i'm not clear.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to send a form parameter indicating which email address should be used. Then you check the POST variable for that parameter in an if statement and set the correct email address to be used.

```
$to = "forma@example.com";
if($_POST['form'] === "formB") {
    $to = "formb@example.com";
}
$mail->addAddress($to, 'Recipient name');
```

Add hidden inputs in your forms named "form" and set the value to either "formA" or "formB":

```
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="formA">
```

Do not set the receiving email address in the form and use that since it can easily be abused to send spam from your server.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution I thought about. But the problem is, my php knowledge doesn't allow me to make this. Could you help me with this?